# Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'

Tags: php, magento, mcrypt

While trying to run magento project in my machine I'm getting this exception `main.CRITICAL: Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'`.

OS version: macOS High Sierra version 10.13.2
php version: PHP 7.1.13 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 15:31:15) ( NTS )

I've added this line in php.ini: `extension="extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-mcrypt/mcrypt.so"`.

Also php71-mcrypt is installed in my machine through brew.

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: @N V R N SATISH Any Solution?

Comment: in which version?